# Find out the glyphs in a font using JS/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, css, web, fonts

Given a font, is it possible using web-dev technologies like JS/PHP or anything else to find out all the glyphs it supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:  Yes.
1 Google search helped me find multiple tools that could help.
https://github.com/Pomax/PHP-Font-Parser
https://code.google.com/p/php-font-lib/source/browse/trunk/www/js/glyph.js?r=50

Possible Duplicate(s) of:
[Extract Font Glyphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253909/extract-font-glyphs)
[get the characters available in TrueType with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5286639/616606)